# Correct use of PlaySound function in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm having some issues utilizing the built-in function PlaySound. I continuously receive two errors, the first being:

> argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR",

and the second being:

> 'BOOL PlaySoundW(LPCWSTR,HMODULE,DWORD)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [35]' to 'LPCWSTR'.

I can't seem to resolve these issues on my own, and would like some help with figuring out how to get rid of the errors. Here's a section of my source code, including what I believe to be causing the error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <dos.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <playsoundapi.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    PlaySound("C:\\Users\\Cristian\\Desktop\\cafe.mp3", NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
    return 0;
}
```

If I am using the PlaySound function incorrectly,please point me to the correct direction.

Answer (score 2):

`LPCWSTR` is a macro for `const wchar_t *` - so you need to use a wide-character `wchar_t` string `L""` instead of a normal `char` string `""`.

```
const wchar_t* path = L"C:\\Users\\Cristian\\Desktop\\cafe.mp3";
PlaySound( path , NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC );
```

The old-school Win32 way would be to use `TCHAR` with optional `#define UNICODE` but this is considered an anachronism as the "ANSI" Win32 functions don't support UCS-2/UTF-16 (and MBCS does not refer to UTF-8, surprisingly).

Note that you probably want to use `SND_SYNC` instead of `SND_ASYNC` because your program will terminate before the sound finishes plaiyng.

Finally, `PlaySound` does not support MP3 files - only Wave files - so your code won't work regardless.

To play MP3 files in Win32 you need to use either:

- MCI (Media Control Interface - an ancient API from the Win3x days, yet surprisingly is the simplest - needing only a two function calls):

  ```
  mciSendString("open \"fileName.mp3\" type mpegvideo alias mp3", NULL, 0, NULL);
  mciSendString("play mp3", NULL, 0, NULL);
  ```
- DirectShow - This is *the* official Windows multimedia API, but it's based on COM and requires you to create a component-graph (file parser, decoders, output devices, etc) so it has a steep learning curve. See here for the minimum code required - almost 60 lines ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389098.aspx )
- Windows Vista introduced MediaFoundation to replace DirectShow, but in my experience it's not much better than DirectShow in terms of programmer-ergonomics: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703190(v=vs.85).aspx
- For Windows 10, there is a WinRT API for playback - but I haven't done much research and I don't know if you can call it from "real" Win32 programs or if it's reserved only for sandboxed UWP applications: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-playback